# Как передать значение активной радиокнопки в массив для вывода на экран?

Tags: javascript, массивы, reactjs

Я новичок в React и работаю над созданием простенького Quiz-виджета, но столкнулся с проблемой: нужно добавлять в массив ответов результат, который хранится в выбранной радиокнопке. Пишу на ReactJS. Заранее благодарен за помощь. Пример кода:

https://codesandbox.io/s/inspiring-mendel-0q2fq

Comment: Зачем для каждого вопроса новый компонент создавать?

Answer (score 1):

Вариантов несколько, самый простой и стремный это прокидывать колбэк функцию в каждый свой компонент, например:
В классе Vote в state добавить answers -

```
this.state = {
      isStarting: false,
      answers: [],
    };
```

Создать коллбэк функцию, которая будет добавлять ответ в этот массив:

```
addAnswer = (answer) => this.setState(prev => ({...prev, answers: [...prev.answers, answer]}));
```

Прокидываем эту функцию в компонент - `<Question1 addAnswer={this.addAnswer}/>`
В компоненте Question1 дописывает функцию:

```
 handleRadioChange(event) {
    this.setState({ option: event.target.value });
    this.props.addAnswer(event.target.value);
  }
```

Соответственно, надо прокинуть во все вопросы эту функцию, а потом в компонент результатов и сам массив с ответами.
Можно еще посмотреть в сторону контекста, что бы не прокидывать колбэк в каждый компонент. Еще бы лучше - не разделять каждый вопрос на разные компоненты